# Chrome debugger features break

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I have a fairly substantial application which i have been developing for a while and i have been able to debug things just fine.
However...
Yesterday i was trying to debug a specific piece of code which seems to break the dev-tools in chrome.

This specific piece of code is the onmessage-callback of a webworker. (Which, as i said, i have been able to debug before)

I have a switch-statement inside to determine which code to execute based on a message in the payload and the debugger only breaks for a specific message.

Any breakpoints i place outside of the callback work just fine but the ones inside (Even before the switch-statement is executed) result in halted code execution with most of the relevant tools disabled.

I have no call-stack, no scope overview, no variable contents when hovering over an identifier.
The breakpoint which got hit is shown under the breakpoint-pane highlighted but in the code window the blue highlight indicating which row of code is about to be executed is missing.

I seem to be able to add watches but that's about it except for resuming execution or single-stepping. (Allthough without seeing which row is about to be executed)

I have tried with chromium as well and some different versions of it but i always get the same result.

My intuition told me that my payload is too big and the debugger breaks because it can't allocate enough memory for the tools but the payload is small compared to payloads i have debugged before.
My question is, what could cause the debugger to break like this?

(Sorry for the lack of example code, there is just too much code required to reconstruct the scenario)

Comment: It could be a bug in devtools, especially if you compile the code and use source maps. Anyway, try adding `debugger;` statement explicitly in your listener's code, and run the page with devtools open.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention but i have had a debugger; statement in there constantly.
I am concatenating the scripts using a gruntfile and i did minify earlier but during development i have disabled the minification for this exact reason.
As i said in my question, the breakpoints do certainly get hit and i can single-step but most of the useful features don't work. (Call-stack, scope etc.)
I have also submitted a bug-report to the chrome-devs but i couldn't isolate the cause of the issue so i have low expectations in regards to that.

Comment: I just tried installing firefox and debugging the same code and it works without issue using the internal debugger. (Didn't even have to download FireBug)

Comment: This is still an issue though as the application i am working on is only targeting Chrome and other vital parts don't work in firefox.